# What are the different schools of thoughts in Hinduism and what is the difference between each of them?

Tags: philosophy, shad-darshana

There are many schools of thought in Hinduism that have their own philosophy and their own way to attain Moksha.

From this Hindu point of view, there are six major schools of orthodox (astika) Indian Hindu philosophy—**Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Samkhya, Yoga, Mīmāṃsā and Vedanta**.

So what are they and what is the difference between each school for the foreign sophistry based research scholars?

Only tell about the major difference between each school of astika

Comment: If there are many such schools then your question becomes "too broad". So, its better to be specific. Btw are you asking about Advaita, Dvaita and Visistadvaita?

Comment: Nyaya, Vaisheshika, Samkhya, Yoga, Mīmāṃsā and Vedanta. 6 schools

Comment: Oh Ok @DarkKnight

Comment: But even now its a broad question. To explain what those schools are and their dissimilarities one may have to write a whole book.

Comment: Just tell what are the difference between each school.

Comment: Better to split the question. The six Astika schools are often grouped into three groups of two: Samkhya-Yoga, Nyaya-Vaisheshika, and Mimamsa-Vedanta. Samkhya-Yoga are similar in almost all respects except for acknowledgment of Ishvara. Nyaya-Vaisheshika are also very similar except for a few things. Therefore, if the question is split into three, the differences of each of the group of two can be discussed.

Comment: Differentiating all of 6 scholars with each other would be too broad

Comment: You can just write about the major differences.

Comment: @GIRIBLR I have to rewrite the entire question

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is taken from this blog

https://tattvamasiblog.wordpress.com/2020/11/28/concise-overview-of-indian-religious-schools-focused-on-hinduism/

based on
“A Critical Survey of Indian Philosophy”, Chandradhar Sharma

[image]

[image]

The above groups Nyaya and Vaisheshika, Samkhya and Yoga. But there are subtle differences within this group also. Mimamsa can not be compared with Vedanta as such as the differences between Advaita and Dvaita are too many.

[Difference between between Nyaya and Vaisheshika](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/20768/what-is-the-difference-between-nyaya-and-vaisheshika?rq=1)

[Difference between Samkhya and Yoga](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/40116/what-are-the-main-philosophical-differences-between-yoga-and-samkhya-darshanas/44228#44228)

Kindly note the word heaven under the state of soul attaining salvation refers to Vaikunta and not swarga loka.

Kindly note that the word soul refers to jiva and not atman

Comment: The text version of this answer, if needed can be found here [rentry.co/HSE-44476](https://rentry.co/HSE-44476). It exceeded the allowed word limit, so it has been hosted externally instead of editing this answer. Edit: Let me know if there are any errors.

Comment: Sir can you please have a look at this qn : https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/q/23596/19211

Comment: Could you add reference for the attached image? I couldn't find that anywhere.