# Do charvakas believe in reincarnation?

Tags: charvaka

Do charvakas believe in reincarnation ? The thing is it is not fitting in quality standards so I have to write this. **just ignore it**

Comment: No, they believe in the philosophy of "materialism", which says that there is no soul, no god, no afterlife, no reincarnation, etc.

Comment: @Ikshvaku Can you answer it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, they do not. The Chárváka system is a materialistic philosophy developed by Brihaspati.

From the [Sarva darshana Samgraha](https://archive.org/details/thesarvadarsanas00madhuoft/page/n37/mode/2up?view=theater)

> *While life is yours, live joyously;*
>
> *None can escape Death's searching eye:*
>
> *When once this frame of ours they burn,*
>
> *How shall it e'er again return?**
>
> *There is no heaven, no final liberation, nor any soul in another
> world,   Nor do the actions of the four castes, orders, &c., produce
> any real effect.*
>
> *If he who departs from the body goes to another world,*
>
> *How is it that he comes not back again, restless for love of his kindred?*
>
> They quote the Śruti for this [Brịhad Áranỵ . Up. ii. 4, 12],
> "Springing forth from these elements, itself solid knowledge, it is
> destroyed when they are destroyed,—after death no intelligence
> remains." Therefore the soul is only the body distinguished by the
> attribute of intelligence, since there is no evidence for any soul
> distinct from the body, as such cannot be proved, since this school
> holds that perception is the only source of knowledge and does not
> allow inference,

Unlike [other schools of philosophy](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/44476/what-are-the-different-schools-of-thoughts-in-hinduism-and-what-is-the-differenc/44487#44487) in Sanatana Dharma, this school believes only in perception as a valid source of knowledge.

Adi Shankara, in his bhashyas and in his [sarva siddhanta samgraha](https://archive.org/details/dli.csl.3538/page/n93/mode/2up), refers to this philosophy as Lokáyatikas. This is said to be a subsect of the Chárváka. However,  Lokáyatikas just means a view prevalent in the world. Shankara refutes this philosophy in great detail. From the sarva siddhanta samgraha,

> verse 6: The Atman is the body itself. It is not distinct from the
> body.
>
> verse 8: Higher than this world is none. There is no heaven or hell.

Edit:

Sarva darshana samgraha is written by Sri Madhava Acharya, a pontiff of Sringeri Math in the lineage of Adi Shankara in 1331 AD.

Sarva siddhanta samgraha is attributed to Adi Shankara.

Comment: Brilliant answer as usual sir !

Comment: @Sethu Srivatsa Koduru Thank you for your kind words sir.