# Where does the soul goes after moksha according to Samkhya?

Tags: moksha, schools

Samkhya is a atheistic school of thought that does not believe in God.

According to Samkhya after moksha soul has consciousness but no bliss.

So where does the soul goes after moksha according to the Samkhya school.

Comment: Sankhya ain't atheistic. It mentions Purusha as the Witness ultimate reality.

Comment: @ParabrahmanJyoti https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44487/22556 see this they do not believe in God

Comment: 'To go somewhere' implies a material spatial location. The jiva is spiritual, not material by definition. It goes nowhere.

Comment: @SwamiVishwananda after moksha according to advaita soul disappears, according to dvaita it lives in Vaikunta. So where does the soul go after moksha according to Samkhya . Because Samkhya believes soul has consciousness after moksha. The question can also be like what happens to the soul after moksha

Comment: You can go through some of these answers. Might be helpful in understanding Samkhya doctrine. In Samkhya things are slightly different. https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/search?q=user:4732%20[sankhya]%20is:answer@DarkKnight