# What kind of knowledge is required to attain Moksha according to advaita vedanta?

Tags: advaita, moksha

According to this [answer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/44487/22556), advaita vedanta goes for the path of knowledge.

What kind of knowledge is required to attain Moksha?

Is it scientific or spiritual knowledge.

Comment: "This Atman is not to be attained by the study of the Vedas, nor by the highest intellect, nor by much learning. Whom the Atman seeks, he gets the Atman; unto him He discloses His glory." Mundaka Upanishad III. ii. 3.  The Atman seeks him who has a deep hankering for Him.

Comment: Self-realization or Atman gyan is needed to attain https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kaivalya Moksha which is last phase of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Puruṣārtha i.e Dharma, Artha, Kama and Moksha. Every common human know themself as Mr. X or Miss Y in their temporary ego of temporary body. "God made sense turn outward, man therefore looks outward, not into himself. Now and again a daring soul, desiring immortality, has looked back and found himself"-Upanishads. Its knowledge of Self aka spirit or Brahmgyan, its science of Self(Atman+mind+body) making person yogi/yogya(competent/worthy).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, it is the knowledge of the Self. That's how Shankara starts all his works.

Atma Bodha, verse 2 and 3

> 2. Just as the fire is the direct cause for cooking, so without Knowledge no emancipation can be had. Compared with all other forms of
>    discipline Knowledge of the Self is the one direct means for
>    liberation.
> 3. Action cannot destroy ignorance, for it is not in conflict with or opposed to ignorance. Knowledge does verily destroy ignorance as light
>    destroys deep darkness.

verse 46

> The ignorance characterised by the notions of I am mine are destroyed
> by the knowledge produced by the realisation of the true nature of the
> Self,